# RDP from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. Authentication Required screen burn in

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, remote-desktop, xrdp

I set up Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS today on my UNRAID system as a VM. I then installed xrdp so I can RDP from Window 10 into my ubuntu box.

Once the RDP window screen locks and I go to log back in. The authentication required pops up, after I put the password it. The screen stays as a screen burn in cover items behind it. Its interactive but putting password in or hitting cancel does not do anything.

Not sure if anyone else has come across this and how to get it to stop

[RDP screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6Cir.jpg)